# Наследование встроенных типов

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Допустим имеется код:

```
class Mylist(list): pass
y = Mylist('abc')
```

Я правильно понимаю что встроенные типы в python также являются полноценными классами(наровне с пользовательскими классами), т.е объекты, например, списка являются экземплярами класса list? Выражение list('abc') по сути является вызовом констуктора класса list. А как методы встроенных типов обрабатывают экземпляры пользовательских классов? Например, в выражении y = Mylist('abc'), как обычно, должен создаваться экземпляр класса Mylist, но метод **init** наследуюмый из класса не возвращает экземпляр класса, а возвращает тип список. Т.е на какое значение будет ссылаться переменная у непонятно.

Comment: @Maksim, не стоит так расстраиваться и удалять текст вопроса.

--

Просто запомните: [oop is evil](http://blog.jot.fm/2010/08/26/ten-things-i-hate-about-object-oriented-programming/)

(особенно это относится к наследованию).

Answer (score 3):

Метод `__init__` в общем случае не должен создавать новые объекты и возвращать их, для этого есть метод [`object.__new__(cls [,...])`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...    def __init__(self):
...        print(" ** MyList **")
...
>>> l1 = MyList()
 ** MyList **
>>> type(l1)
<class '__main__.MyList'>
>>> l2 = MyList.__new__(MyList) # создает объект, но не вызывает __init__
>>> type(l2)
<class '__main__.MyList'>
>>> l2.__init__()
 ** MyList **
```

При этом метод `__new__` (как это и полагается в python) можно переопределить:

```
>>> class Whoa(dict):
...     @staticmethod
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...             return MyList()
...
>>> w = Whoa()
>>> type(w)
<class '__main__.MyList'> # <- обращаем внимание на тип
 ** MyList **
```

Comment: Повторяю ещё раз: метод `__init__` в общем случае не создает новый объект, он вызывается уже после того как объет был создан методом `__new__`.

l1 не является типом, это объект, экземпляр класса MyList, и по совместительству экземпляр класса list, потому что MyList наследует от list.

Comment: Метод `__new__` обычно создает экземпляр того класса, который передан в этот метод первым параметром: сравните `type(list.__new__(list))` и `type(list.__new__(MyList))`

Comment: Выражение `y = MyList()` эквивалентно паре вызовов `y = MyList.__new__(MyList); y.__init__()`. Поскольку класс MyList не определяет свою версию `__new__`, то используется унаследованная от `list`, т.е. первый из двух вызовов эквивалентен `list.__new__(MyList)`.
Что означает выражение `экземпляр класса MyList получает значение при наследовании` мне непонятно.